# socket.io emit in loop until client responds?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I would like to emit a message to the client every X seconds until the client clicks a button and acknowledges receipt.

Any ideas on how I might accomplish this? New to Node but I am hoping I can get this done with Node and Sockets.io.

Thanks in advance for any insight or help to get me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to accomplish this would be to create a new class that extends the "vanilla" Node.js event class. You will need to require it first like so:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');

class MyEmitter extends EventEmitter {}
```

https://nodejs.org/api/events.html

Once you've got your class, what you will need to do is creating a child process, to do so, you can refer to the official documentation here:

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Inside this process you can create your loop and send a message through the socket. The goal of extending the events class is to be able to create an Inside event emission which you can listen to detect specific events (like socket closed, or anything you'd like to track)

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for your response, this is a little over my head skill wise. Appreciate it though and I will dig in more at some point soon as I am sure it's good info, just making my head spin a bit as I am a bit of a node newb still.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple setup just to give you an idea of how to do it:

node server (very basic, only socket.io, nothing else):

```
const io = require('socket.io')(3000);
const interval = 1000;
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log(socket.id + ' has connected');
    var foo = setInterval (function () {
        socket.emit('foo');
    }, interval);   
    socket.on('confirmed', function () {
        console.log('confirmation received from ' + socket.id);
        clearInterval(foo);
    });     
});
console.log('socket.io server started at port 3000');
```

index.html (open it in your browser and see what happens):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Testing socket.io</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="button">Confirm</button>
    <p id="socket">waiting...</p>
    <p id="alert">foos counter: </p>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.7.3/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io("http://localhost:3000");
        var counter;
        socket.on('connect', function() {
          counter = 0;
          document.getElementById("socket").innerHTML = "connected";
          document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function () {
              socket.emit("confirmed");
          });
      });
      socket.on('foo', function() {
          counter++;
          document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = "foos counter: " + counter;
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works really well, I just need to see about adapting it to my specific case. Thanks... Gonna dig in more tonight or tomorrow. I am sure the first answer was good as well but it's a little over my head skill wise.

Comment: OK, let me throw this out there.. What if I don't know the socket.id on the server side? I will basically have lots of people connect but won't be tracking all their socket.id's. Once they connect, they will stay connected for hours or days waiting for the server to send them an alert which they will need to confirm. I guess I am not sure how I will decide how to get the alert to the right client but I thought about doing a broadcast, then filtering the message on the client side. Maybe name spaces will help with that but I need to read up more on name spaces. Sorry not a good explanation.

Comment: Maybe I should track their socket.id's in a DB? So something like this.. Send customer ID from the client when they connect in the browser, set that in a DB record on the server side like socket.id=blah, customerid=329. Then when I have something on the server I need to send to customer 329 I can lookup their current socket.id and send directly to that socket.id?? Maybe I am going off in the woods here but, my gears are turning. Either way, thanks for the help.

Comment: To be clear, I need to send the message to the client, wait 20 seconds for a response from that same client and if I don't get a response from that client, I need to timeout and try the next client etc. until I get a confirmation click.

Comment: And how do you pick the first client? Randomly?